# Yii - What methods to use, in order to process this date change?

Tags: internationalization, yii

I'm not sure where to make this. Here's part of my config file:

```
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'myApp',
        'defaultController' => 'event/index', //events as default
        'language'=>'pt',
        'timeZone'=>'Europe/Lisbon',
        'localeDataPath'=>dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/i18n',

   'components'=>array(
            'format' => array(
                    'datetimeFormat' => 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm',
                    'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    'timeFormat' => 'hh:mm',
            ),
```

So:
I'm retrieving the date as a string like this:

```
'2010-11-02'
```

So I need to convert this string to: 02-11-2010 .

I've tried this:

```
Yii::app()->format->formatDate($data);
```

I get:

> "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Why ?

:s

Update:
Used: yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd', $data); //to return the day;
Used: yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('MMMM', $data); //to return the month;

worked.

Comment: Have you looked at [CDateFormatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter/)?

Comment: I now have. thanks. I've change the config file, and I was excepting the date to change from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `dd/mm/yyyy` . No luck. the data coming from the db still preserves their stored format. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have in config:

```
 'components' => array(
       'format' => array(
            'datetimeFormat' => 'm/d/Y h:i A',
            'dateFormat' => 'm/d/Y',
            'timeFormat' => 'h:i A',
        ),
```

and we use like:

and you can use `Yii::app()->format` to format

Comment: So, when you receive data from the database on `yyyy/mm/dd` you use your format settings to change it. But on this case, I would have the need for two different formats. One for the forms other for presentation views as stated on original question. So I guess I can't follow that path. Anyway, is `format` an alternative method of `CDateFormatter` ? thanks.

Comment: format is an application component, and it's a wrapper to CDateFormatter. The format method takes format parameters, it's up to you what parameters you give.

Comment: Ok. I've tried that. A date is coming from my database as `yyyy-mm-dd` and I wish to convert it as `dd/mm/yyyy` so I've made the appropriate changed on config. However, the date doesn't get formated. It preserves the mysql returned format. Shouldn't that change automatically ?